# How to divide dataset by grouping data?

Tags: oracle

I have a table with column of Depth, it ranges from 0 to 1000m with interval of 1m. I like to group them into every 10m with average value for each 10m to save time.  How to do it? Thank you so much.

Here is my code without grouping on depth column.

Also wondering does this reducing num of data rows will increase query SPEED?

```
start='2022-01-01' 
end='2022-03-01' 
sql = 
f""" SELECT 
WELL_NAME, ROUND(OBV_TIME,'DDD') as "Date",
 DEPTH, AVG(TEMPERATURE) as "TEMPERATURE"
 FROM
 TEMPERATURE_V 
WHERE 
AREA_NAME = 'Lake' AND WELL_NAME = '{well}' 
AND OBV_TIME >= TO_DATE('{start}', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND OBV_TIME <= TO_DATE('{end}','YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND DEPTH>={dts_well_depth_min} 

GROUP BY 
WELL_NAME, ROUND(OBV_TIME,'DDD'), DEPTH """
```

Comment: Can you write a query against an unknown table?  Can you test a query with no data?  Please read about creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I found a solution using 10*trunc(depth/10,0) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using 10*trunc(depth/10,0) and it works.

```
      SELECT 
         WELL_NAME,
         OBV_TIME,
         10*TRUNC(DEPTH/10,0) as "DEPTH_10",
         AVG(TEMPERATURE) as "TEMPERATURE"                  
      FROM TEMPERATURE_V
      WHERE
         AREA_NAME = 'Lake'
         AND WELL_NAME = '{well}'
         AND OBV_TIME >= TO_DATE('{start}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         AND OBV_TIME <= TO_DATE('{end}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         AND DEPTH>={dts_well_depth_min}
      GROUP BY WELL_NAME, OBV_TIME, 10*TRUNC(DEPTH/10,0)
```